# Unable to load a CSS static resource even with Developer org

Tags: api, css, static-resources

## Problem

I am currently inside a Developer Sandbox within Salesforce.  Inside the developer console I am able to create static resources of the MIME type text/CSS. I know this because they show up when I display static resources:
[image: Open Static Resources]

However, whenever I attempt to load these static resources, it gives me this error:
[image]

Normally, it appears for [non-developer](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008soLIAQ) orgs, but I also get this following error window as well:

[image]

Which leads me to believe something more subtle is going on.

## **Question**

Regardless, how do I properly load a CSS static resource in a developer org?

Comment: under Setup > Company Information, what is the Organization Edition ? (just to confirm) where you are getting the api disables for this org message?

Comment: @glls Just checked, its the professional edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the edition features, or [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005140&type=1) kb article, professional édition orgs do not have API access enabled, hence the error