# How to change the organization edition as a System Administrator?

Tags: professional-edition, developer-edition, editions

## Problem

Off [another question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202742/unable-to-load-a-css-static-resource-even-with-developer-org) I am trying to do an operation that requires the Developer Edition of Salesforce, which I found out was not the case.

## Question

How, as a Sytem Administrator account, do I change the edition of Salesforce from Professional to Developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't be done. You can, however, create a free developer org [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup?d=70130000000td6N). Then by extracting your org's metadata using your tool of choice (Ant, Eclipse, Mavensmate), you can load the metadata into your newly created org.